What's "call" mean in "A call issued to party members in a lawmaking body to ensure attendance at a particular time."
One of the definitions for the headword "whip" in the American Heritage Dictionary 2016 edition is:

b. A call issued to party members in a lawmaking body to ensure attendance at a particular time.

Does the word "call" in this context mean "demand" as in this Merriam Webster's definition?

DEMAND, CLAIM
The aircraft industry continues to have first call on aluminum production.
—Americana Annual

There is also a phrase "issue a call for (something)" which would further suggest to me that this is in fact true.
"issue a call for (something)"
To formally or publicly request or ask for something.
The mayor issued a call for donations after the town was devastated by flooding.(Farlex Dictionary of Idioms)

Yes it does mean demand.

A Call to Arms.

I'd use it more as an invitation or appeal than a demand: A call for submissions, a call for quotes, a call for job applications.

It's also used in securities trading (puts and calls).

The best M-W definition for this sense of "call" is:

2 a : a request or command to come or assemble

In this case, it's a command for lawmakers to assemble.
While a command to assemble is a demand, that's a misleading coincidence because that sense of "demand" is not a synonym for "claim". In the definition "DEMAND, CLAIM", the relevant M-W entry for "demand" is:

1 b : something claimed as due or owed

This is not the sense of "call" in the American Heritage Dictionary definition of "whip".
